# Absolute positioned element is invisible even when setting high z-index

Tags: html, css, css-position, absolute

Code pen showcasing problem.

https://s.codepen.io/NoMan2000/debug/rdPEYJ/xnrabdnqJadA

I apologize for the rather gnarly HTML, but this is output from a next.js project so the bloated mess is part and parcel of that.

Anyway, the problem can be seen in the element `#header-menu-buttonList`.  The idea is pretty simple, a menu that goes underneath the main grid element.  But for whatever reason, it just sits there on the page.

You can pick it up in the debug tools and see that it has a width and a height.  Messing with its z-index doesn't make the object visible, only removing the `position: absolute` makes it visible on the page, but that opens up a whole host of other issues.

So, anyone know:

1.)  Why the heck it's doing that?
2.)  How to either fix it or work around it?

Comment: What is the main grid element? What do you click to activate your issue? You're getting some CORS errors in the console.

Comment: Main element is `#header-menu-button-list`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the rubber-ducking. :)

So the issue is that the parent element is positioned absolutely, and the child element is positioned absolutely.  I'm not up to snuff on all my CSS rules, but this appears to keep it in the DOM but not render it visible.

The solution is to set the child `#header-menu-buttonList` to `position: static` and the parent `#header-menu-button` to `position:absolute`.